# Inner join in collections using LINQ

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq, collections

I have two collections and i have to make a join to get a value, but when i tried its throwing me error.

//Code:

```
 Dim ExclusiveComment As ExclusiveComments = Nothing

ExclusiveComment = From ExclusiveCommentLinq In Me.ExclusiveCommentsCollection
                   Join ExistingCommentsLinq In Me.CombinedExclusiveCommentsCollection On      ExclusiveCommentLinq.CommentDescription Equals ExistingCommentsLinq(0)
                   Select ExclusiveCommentLinq
```

In the above code,

`ExclusiveCommentsCollection`= Collection of class(ExclusiveComments)
 `CombinedExclusiveCommentsCollection` = Regular string collection(Single column)

Both collection have common column "`CommentDescription`" with which i need to get the value from `ExclusiveCommentsCollection`.

Can u tel me where i'm wrong and  how to achieve this?.

**Error:**

Option strict on  disallows implicit conversions from  'System.collections.generic.ienumarable(Of ExclusiveComments to ExclusiveComments)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that a join always results in a "list" of objects, even if that list only contains one object.  In this case, you only need to qualify your query with a "FirstOrDefault" at the end to indicate that you only want to use one result.

```
Dim ExclusiveComment As ExclusiveComments = Nothing
ExclusiveComment = (From ExclusiveCommentLinq In Me.ExclusiveCommentsCollection
                   Join ExistingCommentsLinq In Me.CombinedExclusiveCommentsCollection On      ExclusiveCommentLinq.CommentDescription Equals ExistingCommentsLinq(0)
                   Select ExclusiveCommentLinq).FirstOrDefault
```

Comment: Its now giving me "index out of the bounds array" error. How to give for the string collection? in the query.

Comment: I think the "ExistingCommentsLinq(0)" is the problem.  You are saying that you want ExclusiveCommentLinq.CommentDescription equal the first item in the ExistingCommentsLinq.  If that is the case, use a separate variable defined outside the Linq.

Comment: No, i want to search in the entire collection and return the result. How can i do that?

Comment: Assuming Me.CombinedExclusiveCommentsCollection is defined as a List(Of String) or some other collection (Of String), you can just use ExistingCommentsLinq instead of ExistingCommentsLinq(0).